# Any solution to select the dropdown value rather than first index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have five options with same values in it. Is there any way to select all the indexes of option tag rather than first index.

Consider this js fiddle for the same

```js
var duplicates = [];

function checkResult(){
var box1 = document.getElementById('box_g1');
var box2 = document.getElementById('box_g2');
var box3 = document.getElementById('box_g3');
var box4 = document.getElementById('box_g4');
var box5 = document.getElementById('box_g5');

var b1 = box1.options[box1.selectedIndex].value;
var b2 = box2.options[box2.selectedIndex].value;
var b3 = box3.options[box3.selectedIndex].value;
var b4 = box4.options[box4.selectedIndex].value;
var b5 = box5.options[box5.selectedIndex].value;
    
console.log(b1);
console.log(b2);
console.log(b3);
console.log(b4);
console.log(b5);    

var arr  = [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5];
var hash = [];

for (var n=arr.length; n--; ){
   if (typeof hash[arr[n]] === 'undefined' ) hash[arr[n]] = [];
   
    hash[arr[n]].push(n);
}

for (var key in hash){
    if (hash.hasOwnProperty(key) && hash[key].length > 1){
        duplicates.push(key);
    }
}

if(duplicates.length > 0){
    alert("duplicate found");
}else{
     alert("No duplicate");   
}
duplicates.length =0;    
}
```

```html
<select name="n1" id="box_g1">
    <option value="Default">Default</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<br/>

<select name="n2" id="box_g2">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select name="n3" id="box_g3">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select name="n4" id="box_g4">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select name="n5" id="box_g5">
    <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>

<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Check Result" onclick="checkResult();"/>
```

I did some trick. But not able to identify, whether it is possible or not.

For box2, box3, box4 and box5, if the user select 'Disbaled' option for any of the boxes rather than box1.

the user will be shown a pop up : "Duplicates found".

Currently, if i select **"Disabled"** option, it shows duplicate found which i dont want.

Comment: `hash` is an array, its indexes should be integers. But `arr[n]` is a string. You should use an object, not an array.

Comment: In your first `for` loop can you not just check `if(arr[n] != "Disabled")` before you add to `hash`?

Comment: BTW, you can just write `var b1 = box1.value;`. The value of a select is the value of its selected option.

Comment: well i think it works with arr[n] !="Disabled" condition. But i am using it in js fiddle with no-wrap (head) condition. It works well there but not in my system.. Do we have to put that code in head tag as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I have change the design.